# FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted! for Virtual Box for Winxp-ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am using OSX-Yosemite

I've downloaded winxp-ie8 but when I try and use it I get

> FATAL: No bootable medium found!  System halted! for Virtual Box for Winxp-ie8

I tried changing my settings as suggested in other answers to this problem but it hasn't helped.

Currently my settings are:

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer to this.
btw surprised at the downvotes and close votes - this seems like a fairly reasonable question with no existing answers.

I've now found the answer to this and it can help many other folks so here it is:

A key part to getting it to work is the Hard Drive selection.

You will see a pop-up about Hard Drive with three options:

- Do not add a virtual hard drive
- Create a virtual hard drive now
- Use an existing virtual hard drive file

I had been assuming I could just choose the middle option, create it now.  I also tried the first option but that seemed to imply no OS at all.

So in fact it is the 3rd option -

### Use an existing virtual hard drive file

and you use it to select an image that you have downloaded and unzipped, e.g. a `.vmdk` file

and then you have:

[image]

The next challenge is to figure out the network piece!